# Spring Security XML configuration can not find my dataSource beans definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security

My `WEB-INF/web.xml` does the following -

1) Loads my servlet context - `WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml`

2) Loads my spring security config file - `WEB-INF/spring-security.xml`

3) Adds a `springSecurityFilterChain` filter to intercept incoming URLs

## `web.xml`

```
<!-- Load spring-web-service.xml Servlet Definition -->

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <!-- Programmatically add the property sources for the current Spring Profile -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.galapagos.context.CustomEnvironmentApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security - Intercept incoming requests for authentication -->

<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

## `spring-web-servlet.xml`

The servlet context is what actually defines my `dataSource` bean that connects to my DB (it also loads properties beforehand)

```
...

<!-- Load Properties -->

<beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
</beans:bean>

<!-- Database / JDBC -->

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
  <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans:bean>

...
```

## `spring-security.xml`

The issue is that the second file that `web.xml` calls out to (my `WEB-INF/spring-security.xml` file) also uses a database connection because it looks for roles and credentials stored in the DB

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

  <!-- access denied page -->
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

  <form-login
    login-page="/login"
    default-target-url="/"
    authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
    username-parameter="email"
    password-parameter="password" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />

  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
  <csrf/>
</http>

<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
  <jdbc-user-service
    data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=?"
    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT email, role FROM user_roles WHERE email=?" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When running I get the error -

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

My best guess is because `dataSource` is defined in the first XML config (`WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml`), it's not available for use in the latter (`WEB-INF/spring-security.xml`)

Is this right?

And if so what's the best way to define a `dataSource` bean so that all the individual XML files can call it as needed? I assume I might add several other components that also require DB access at some point.

Thanks!

Comment: why have multiple configuration files? Do you actually need to?

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml try changing this

contextConfigLocation
  /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,  WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml  

This will help you.